# Injecting Jasper parameters into field specifications

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to have shared (template) .JRXML files that work for a variety of XML datasources.

The only thing I know of that might prevent this is that the field specifications would be slightly different.

For one XML file the XPATH for a name field might be:

```
   person/name/last
```

For another XML file the XPATH might be:

```
   contact/last_name
```

Ideally I could pass the XPATH in as a parameter and use it like:

```
 <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription> $P{NAME_XPATH} </fieldDescription>
</field>
```

But Jasper doesn't seem to support the use of parameters in `<fieldDescription>` tags.

Is the some way for me to inject the field specification into my JRXML templates?

Comment: In case you're wondering "why" I need to do this...

I have built a framework that allows the entire specification of a report to be done as "data" so that the entire system is data-driven.   The goal is to NOT have to write code for any new report: you only write a report configuration file in XML and use the JRXML templates.

Answer (score 0):

As your system is XML based, why not use XSLT? Your JRXML template can be adapted to be an XSL stylesheet, then using your XML config file as input, an XSLT processor can replace the field descriptions with the config content.

Example: 
**JRXML/XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/report-config">

    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd">

    ...

    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><xsl:value-of select="name"/></fieldDescription>
    </field>

    ...

    </jasperReport>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Config XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<report-config>
    <name>person/name/last</name>
</report-config>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  We actually had considered that, but feel that the overhead seemed high:

1) loading the original JRXML into a DOM, 
2) loading the stylesheet into a DOM
3) invoking the XSLT transformer, 
4) creating a whole new DOM in memory, 
5) writing it out (not sure if JasperCompilerManager accepts a DOM), 6) reading it back in, 
7) compiling it.

Answer (score 0):

Jasper doesn't support the use of parameters in `<fieldDescription>` tags.

I downloaded the Jasper sources and I don't think you can add this capability by simply implementing an alternative `XPathExecutor`.   The reason is because the context that contains the parameters is not available to the XPathExecutor factory classes.  In short, there's a lot of context passing that needs to be added.

You could of course try adding it, but it would affect many class files and then it becomes the sort of change that Jasper might not pick up, and you'd be left forever merging your diverged sources.

I wasn't prepared to risk that.  Plus, I think sooner or later, Jasper will add this.

However, I did come up with a solution which basically involves writing your own custom XPathExecutor and then passing the context into it via a Threadlocal variable implementation.  In the example code below, the Threadlocal variable is `ReportGeneratorJasper.requestContext`

```
static ThreadLocal<ReportRequest> requestContext;
```

Here is the code to setup the custom XPathExecutor in my class `ReportGeneratorJasper`:

```
    JasperReport repResource = getJasperReport(report);
    JasperPrint jp = null;

    // Setup for eReports XPATH executers
    //
    JasperReportsContext jrc = DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance();
    jrc.setProperty(
        JRXPathExecuterUtils.PROPERTY_XPATH_EXECUTER_FACTORY, 
        XalanNamedParameterXPathExecutor.class.getCanonicalName());

    requestContext = 
               new ThreadLocal<ReportRequest>() {
                         protected synchronized ReportRequest initialValue() {
                         return request;
             };
    };

    JasperFillManager jfm = JasperFillManager.getInstance(jrc);
```

ReportRequest is my own bean that contains all the properties that define "this" particular report generation request.

Here is the custom XPathExecutor (which also provides its own factory).  :

```
public class XalanNamedParameterXPathExecutor 
            extends XalanXPathExecuter implements JRXPathExecuterFactory {

    // Reference to the Threadlocal
    //
    private ReportRequest request;

    public static final String PREFIX = "$";

    public XalanNamedParameterXPathExecutor() {
        this.request = ReportGeneratorJasper.requestContext.get();
    }

    @Override
    public Object selectObject(Node arg0, String xpath) throws JRException {

        String useXpath = xpath;

        if (xpath.startsWith("$")) {
            String value = request.getScalarParamAsString(xpath);
            useXpath = (value != null ? value : xpath);         
        }

        return super.selectObject(arg0, useXpath);
    }

    @Override
    public JRXPathExecuter getXPathExecuter() {
        return new XalanNamedParameterXPathExecutor();
    }
```

Using Threadlocal isn't an ideal solution.   It's prone to breaking if the report filler is run in a different thread.   But in the current version of Jasper, it seems not to be a problem.

Hopefully Jasper will implement builtin support for this.